# K Framework: Substitution not substituting in simple terms?

Tags: kframework

I have the following K file:

```
require "substitution.k"

module PURE
    imports DOMAINS
    imports SUBSTITUTION

    syntax PSort ::= "$Type" [token]
                   | "$Kind" [token]

    syntax Type ::= PSort
                  | KVar
                  | "Pi" KVar ":" Term "." Term [binder]

    syntax Term ::= Type
                  | "(" Term ")" [bracket]
                  > Term Term    [left]
                  > "declare" KVar ":" Term "in" Term

    syntax KResult ::= Type

    configuration
    <T>
        <k> typeof($PGM:Term, ?T) ~> ?T </k>
        <typeEnv> .Map </typeEnv>
    </T>

    syntax KItem ::= typeof(Term, Term)

    rule <k> typeof(declare X : T in E, T2) => typeof(E, T2) ... </k>
         <typeEnv> TEnv => TEnv[X <- T] </typeEnv>

    // VAR
    rule <k> typeof(X:KVar, T) => . ... </k>
         <typeEnv> ... X |-> T ... </typeEnv>

    // APP
    syntax KItem ::= Term "=" Term
    rule T = T => .

    rule typeof(M N, T) =>
         typeof(M, Pi ?X : ?T1. ?T2) ~>
         typeof(N, ?T1) ~>
         ?T2[N/?X] = T
endmodule
```

When I compile it with the Java backend and run the following file:

```
declare nat : $Type in
declare Z : nat in
declare Vector : Pi n : nat . $Type in
declare blah : Pi n : nat . (Vector n) in
blah Z
```

I get:

```
<T>
  <k>
    Vector n
  </k>
  <typeEnv>
    Vector |-> Pi n : nat . $Type
    Z |-> nat
    blah |-> Pi n : nat . ( Vector n )
    nat |-> $Type
  </typeEnv>
</T>
```

But I want it to substitute `Z` for `n` and get `Vector Z`.

Comment: Which rule do you feel should cause the substitution?

Comment: @nishantjr The very last rule. I also tried storing the result of the substitution in another cell in the configuration so I could debug, but it didn't work there either so I'm pretty sure the way I wrote the rules isn't the issue---even if it's nonstandard.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in the java backend that prematurely applies the substitution operator while its arguments are still symbolic variables. As a result, the substitution operator disappears prematurely, and then when the term that was substituted is instantiated via unification, it has not been substituted, which leads to the problem that you describe. Here is an issue tracking the problem: https://github.com/kframework/k/issues/1165

I took a stab at fixing it, but it proved to be nontrivial and I don't have time to dig deeper right now. You are welcome to try to fix it in a pull request if you want, although I am unsure why the fix I wrote is making other things break. Your better choice is probably to rewrite your typing rules so that they don't try to perform substitution on a variable. One way to do this would be to make the rule for application modify the type environment and then restore it when it's been fully typed. You can take a look at the K tutorial folder 1_k/5_types for some examples of how you can type a lambda-calculus-like language.